# Character tables of finite groups in positive characteristic - not the modular case

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $F$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$ with $p \nmid |G|$. So, the group algebra $F[G]$ is semisimple.

What are the techniques to compute the character table of $G$ over $F$? In representations over $\mathbb{C}$, I have the orthogonality relations of characters. What tools do I have in my case?

Comment: Under these conditions, are the Brauer characters not just equal to the complex characters?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I don't know the Brauer characters. I'll look them up now.

Comment: If you don't know Brauer characters, then what do you mean by characters? We don't usually just take traces of the representations in positive characteristic (as this just loses way too much information).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I class we learned about complex representations, so I made up this problem to extend my understanding. I don't have an application in mind.

Comment: @Gils: Calculate the complex characters. They will be elements of $R=\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{p^n-1}]$ for some $n$. In the finite field $F_0 \leq F$ of order $p^n$ choose some primitive root $z \in F_0$ of multiplicative order $p^n-1$. There is a ring homomorphism from $R$ to $F_0$ sending $\zeta$ to $z$. The (Frobenius) characters of $G$ over $F$ are the images of the $\mathbb{C}$-characters of $G$ under that homomorphism.